# Rails, order by nested value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this classes:

```
class Fruit
 attr_accessible :name, :position
 has_many :apples
 default_scope order('position ASC')
end

class Apple
 attr_accessible :name
 belongs_to :fruit
end
```

How sort apples by fruit.position?

Answer (score 23):

Sorry guys, I think it must be like this: `@apples.joins(:fruit).order("fruits.position")`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

`@apples.joins(:fruit).order(Fruit.arel_table[:position])`